# Is there a way DJANGO to create a specific Form instance?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a form with a `ModelMultipleChoiceField()` field. The form is used to send a message to user's friends. That means that instead of a generic queryset (e.g. `Friends.objects.all()`) I want to put something like `queryset = user.friends.all()`.

Is this possible?

Comment: That depends what your user model looks like. How are you storing who a given user's friends are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
#forms.py
class YourForm:
    def __init__(data, user):
       self.base_fields['your_field'].queryset = user.friends.all()
       super(YourForm, self).__init__(data)


#views.py
def your_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = YourForm(request.POST, request.user)
    else:
        form = YourForm(user=request.user)
    [...]
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to make a closure.  Don't worry if you don't know what that is, just define your Form **inside** your view like this

```
def my_view(...):
    user = ...
    class MessageForm(ModelForm):
        friends = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=user.friends.all())
        text = ...
    form = MessageForm(...)
```

There are other ways but that is by far the easiest.